# Need a tool or apps to measure WiFi Routers Transmission power output

Tags: wifi, router, android-wifi

All android apps or other tools available give signal strength (RSSI) values that is received signal but how to see transmission output power from router. I want to calculate propagation loss.

Need a tool or apps to measure WiFi Routers Transmission power output.

Thanks,
Jyoti

Comment: Check manufacturers specifications

Comment: I checked that but I think even though specification says 18dBm, but power is usually adaptively adjusted, cannot be 18 all the time. So need some tools or app to know TX power.

Answer (score 0):

iwlist - if you can get linux command line on a device.  It returns basic info about wifi signals in range.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/wireless-tools#iwlist

https://linux.die.net/man/8/iwlist

Comment: I have TP-Link 841n (V10) router. To run linux command, do I need to install OpenWrt firmware again or I can run linux command directly connecting router via serial console??

Comment: or Can i run this command from my linux computer to see tx power of my router?

Comment: Run iwlist on a separate machine.  It won't give you the exact strength as what is being fed to the emitter, but you can configure cron to run and dump to file so you can get idea of signal strength variability.

Comment: There is also an app called "wifi analyzer".

Comment: Let's say I am running a iwlist on my linux machine.                                     I think it will show the TX power of Wi-Fi transceiver of my laptop not router. My requirement is to find the tx power emitted by router not laptop. WiFi analyzer android app gives the received signal strength not tx power.

Comment: Iwlist does provide strength of received signal.  See iwlist.scan

Comment: Received signal has lower power than transmitted power. I want to see transmitted power. The power listed in the specification is not always transmitted by router. So need to check what actually the TX power is and see calculate the propagation loss from Pt and Pr values.

Comment: is  lwlist scan similar to RSSI value shown in wifi analyzer?

Comment: Try running iw dev *device* info on your openwrt router

Comment: So, router automatically does not come with open wrt right? You mean installing openwrt firmware on router?

Comment: Sorry, misread your first comment as saying that you did have openwrt on the device.  Of course installing that might change signal power behaviour.  I can't think of a way to do what you want to do easily, I would use iwlist to observe signal power and infer from that.  I'm just a layman, you sound more knowledgeable than me...